# Randomly select and play audio property of object

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a spelling bee web app for the school I work at. My idea is to have the students click on a button, which will randomly select and play the audio of a word. Then, they will write the word on the form and submit for correction.

This is my prototype code

1st, an object with the words names and audio files.

```
var words = {}
words.carrot = {
audio : new Audio ('http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english-portuguese/uk_pron/u/ukc/ukcar/ukcarap002.mp3'),
name : "CARROT"
}
words.ball = {
audio : new Audio ('http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/media/english/us_pron/b/bal/ball_/ball.mp3'),
name : "BALL"
}
```

Then, a function that randomly selects a property of the object. It would be called by clicking on a button.

```
var play = function(){

var list = Object.keys(words);

var randomWord = list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length) ];
}
```

So far, so good.

What I don't manage to do is to incorporate the resulting word back into the objects syntax.
For the sake of testing, I tried the following:

```
document.getElementById("demoparagraph").innerHTML = randomWord
```

And it perfectly shows one of the properties.

But this doesn't work: `words.randomWord.audio`. It returns "undefined".

Whereas `words.carrot.audio` works just fine.

Comment: You're misunderstanding javascript objects. words.carrot works because carrot is a property. You have created an object with two properties, carrot and ball. Not an array with two options.

Comment: You need to use bracket notation `words[randomWord].audio`

Comment: The bracket notation worked! Thanks!